# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied gets thrown when starting the script in CGI, but not in bash

Tags: python, bash, apache2, cgi, centos7

When I access the script via CGI, a PermissionError gets thrown, but when I start the same script with bash over SSH, it works fine.

I tried temporarily modifying the sudoers file, so that the script would always be run as root.

```
import socket                                                                                                                                                             
print("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n")
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
query = 'foobar'
sock.sendall(bytes(query, 'utf-8'))
buffer = sock.recv(1024)
responce = str(buffer, "UTF-8")
print(responce)
```

When the script is run with bash, no error is thrown, even when I login as a normal non-superuser account, but when I run it by accessing a webpage, it writes an error to /etc/httpd/logs/error_log.
The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/cgi-bin/script.py", line 8, in <module>
sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Comment: What are the permissions of `script.py`?

Comment: Any user can read, write, and execute it(777), but the file is owned by root.

Comment: Ah, my fault. Sorry for my sloppy reading. The permissions of the script don't matter, because the script does get executed. It is the `connect` which is rejected....

Comment: Even when I log on as the user 'apache', which is used by the web server to run the scripts, it still works. The error only happens when I try to access it via a web page.

Comment: What is HOST and PORT set to?

Comment: HOST is set to '127.0.0.1', and PORT to 4345.

Comment: I tried to do the same thing on a different machine(setup apache, and copy the script), and it works fine when I run it via the browser. My second machine is running Ubuntu. How can I fix it?

Comment: Just a wild guess: If you set HOST to `localhost`, you get the same behaviour? There should be no difference, but sometimes the two are not treated identically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior was SELinux's fault. When I set 'httpd_can_network_connect' to 'on' with setsebool, the script works fine. Note, that to make the change permanent across reboots, you must use the -P switch.